# PHP: redirect after get url

Tags: php, redirect, simple-html-dom

I need "calculate" an URL and redirect to it. I have the following code:

```
<?php

//Basic HTML parsing with PHP
    include("simple_html_dom.php");

    $htmlCode = file_get_html('http://example.net/example.html');

    foreach($htmlCode->find('div[class=frontPageImage]') as $element) {

        foreach($element->find('img') as $imagee)
            $imgurl = $imagee->src;
    }

header("'Location:".$imgurl."'");

?>
```

First in $imgurl get the url and later redirect to that url... but it doesn't work..

any idea or suggestion? thanks

Comment: Can you guarantee that the SRC attribute of the images will always contain the full URL?  If they're using relative paths, you'll likely have problems.  Also, what's your expectation for multiple images?  Redirect to the first one?

Comment: To get the last image, use `$imgurl = $htmlCode->find('div[class=frontPageImage] img')->last_child()->src;`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
header("'Location:".$imgurl."'");
```

Should probably be:

```
header("Location: " . $imgurl);
```

I removed the single quote `'` because your HTTP header would look like:

```
'Location: http://site.com/image.jpg'
```

which is invalid because of the single quotes.

You are also looping and finding many image URL's but only redirecting to the last one.

Comment: Thanks drew010, the problem was de quote! And yes I only want redirect the last one. Thanks a lot!